# MyBatis: How to return a list of id's or updated rows after an update execution?

Tags: java, mybatis

While you can obtain the id of the inserted row with `useGeneratedKeys` for an insert execution, how about an update execution? Is it possible to get a list of ids or objects of the updated rows using MyBatis? I couldn't find anything related to this problem. This is especially useful when the rows to update are randomly selected so the query of these rows would be difficult to determine afterwards.

Comment: Maybe call a stored procedure instead of an update directly and put some logic in there.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If yes, please humour us.